# JAVA : Parsing the Xml Value using javax.ml and Xpath option

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have an XmlParserClass to get values from the xml file which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HomePageData>
<LogoTopLeft>//*[@id='corp_logo']</LogoTopLeft>
<SingInLink>//*[@id='login']</SingInLink>
<SingUpLink>//*[@id='signup']</SingUpLink>
</HomePageData>
```

And the method in my class file looks like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
try{
        String value = xp.evaluate("/LogoTopLeft/text()", doc); 
        return value;
    } catch(XPathExpressionException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

I am not able to get the expected data from the xml file using this class file. It just reaches the try block and then come to the catch to return "null". Most of the question in stackoverflow has been answered with a for loop to collect all nodes, but I need to take one data at a time not allelements at one stretch and Also, I need to return this value to another class file which will accept only STRINGS and so I cant pass NodeList or any other elements

P.S - The xml file is present in a different location other than the parsefile. I stored the class path value "/projName/src/com/core/path/indexPage.xml" in a file and passed it.

Comment: You should really add e.printStackTrace(); before the return null; statement. That might already help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I have that e.printStackTrace exception as well. But it is not helping me. am getting a Nullpointer exception..                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.xpath.axes.AxesWalker.setRoot(AxesWalker.java:221)
 at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIterator.setRoot(WalkingIterator.java:157)
 at org.apache.xpath.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:265)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to fix your XPath. `/LogoTopLeft` is looking for the element at XML root whereas it's a child element. So, either use `//LogoTopLeft` or specify the full path as `/HomePageData/LogoTopLeft`

```
String logo = xp.evaluate("//LogoTopLeft/text()", doc);
String signIn = xp.evaluate("//SignInLink/text()", doc);
String signUp = xp.evaluate("//SignUpLink/text()", doc);

System.out.println( "logo = " + logo +
                    "; signIn = " + signIn +
                    "; signUp = " + signUp);
/* prints:
   logo = //*[@id='corp_logo']; signIn = //*[@id='login']; signUp = //*[@id='signup']
*/
```

***EDIT** : (My Test Code)*

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                   .newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("input.xml"));

XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

try {
    String logo = xp.evaluate("/HomePageData/LogoTopLeft/text()", doc);
    String signIn = xp.evaluate("//SignInLink/text()", doc);
    String signUp = xp.evaluate("//SignUpLink/text()", doc);

    System.out.println( "logo = " + logo +
                        "; signIn = " + signIn +
                        "; signUp = " + signUp);
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***input.xml** (placed in project directory)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HomePageData>
    <LogoTopLeft>//*[@id='corp_logo']</LogoTopLeft>
    <SignInLink>//*[@id='login']</SignInLink>
    <SignUpLink>//*[@id='signup']</SignUpLink>
</HomePageData>
```

Comment: thanks Ravi. I am still getting the same error message. Actually I missed a line of code. File file = new File(//projectName/src/com/core/path/launchPage.xml);                           Can you confirm if this is correct as well?

Comment: @Akash, I actually rewrote the program and fixed some typos. Let me share.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I will try this code. But is it fine to ignore the relative path of the xml file. because I have the xml in com.core.path and the java file is in com.core.datamodel ??

Comment: If you want to keep your file within package use `Class.getReourceAsStream()`. Otherwise your code would break on deployment as it won't have project directories.

Comment: Thanks Ravi,                                                        doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("/src/com/core/path/launchPage.xml"));                      I am still stuck at this code, Can you fix this xpath please. I can not have java and xml file in same package as they are many such files and it would be easy for me to organize.

Comment: @Akash, where are you calling this code from? Is it within an instance method or main() method of some class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35544/discussion-between-akash-and-ravi-thapliyal)